# Linker can't find 'get_int_member_with_default' from json-glib

Tags: json, linker-errors, glib, vala

I am currently working on a library that interacts with a REST API. This API responds with a JSON object, which I'm parsing with json-glib-1.0. As some of the members of the object might not exist I wanted to use the get_x_member_with_default function of the Json.Object class.
Even though both the Vala and the C compiler see the functions the linker gives me several errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_json_object_get_boolean_member_with_default", referenced from:
      _discord_message_construct in message-f5c60f.o
  "_json_object_get_int_member_with_default", referenced from:
      _discord_message_construct in message-f5c60f.o
  "_json_object_get_string_member_with_default", referenced from:
      _discord_message_construct in message-f5c60f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

To reproduce this you can try this code:

```
void main() {
    string json = "{\"one\": 1337}";
    Json.Parser parser = new Json.Parser();
    parser.load_from_data(json, -1);
    int64 val = parser.get_root().get_object().get_int_member_with_default("one", 666);
    stdout.printf(@"$val\n");
}
```

and compile it with this command: `valac --pkg json-glib-1.0 file.vala`.
This gives me

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_json_object_get_int_member_with_default", referenced from:
      __vala_main in json2-ec99c2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is obviously not a library; when compiling my library I only generate the C code and compile and link everything with the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs json-glib-1.0`. Is there anything I have to link additionally?

Comment: are you using a build system like meson? that'll make your life a lot easier

Comment: For my library I use a Makefile, nothing more and this wouldn't change anything I guess

Comment: Makefile is effectivly just a bash script at heart and you'll find it painfully once you have many sources and want to use things like GResource, meson would keep track of cflags for you

Comment: I'm also wondering what platform your on, _ prefix would suggest Windows but vala seems to have choosen clang suggesting macOS

Comment: I am on MacOs @AlexB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install a newer version of json-glib, or more likely, not use that symbol. The [Vala documentation for the symbol](https://valadoc.org/json-glib-1.0/Json.Object.get_int_member_with_default.html) shows this is since version 1.6 of the library. This information is taken from the C source for the library and the symbol was added with [this commit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/json-glib/commit/5b816ff8df9e563c1e9c3ae05ee97d46924f9b40). The problem is the latest stable release appears to be 1.4.4 - see the [source repository tags](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/json-glib/-/tags). So it looks like you have to build your own development version with the latest symbols or not use `get_int_member_with_default ()`.